# prompted for entering password to download the play framework

Tags: playframework

I am trying to download the Play framework 2.3.5, but I keep getting prompted for password before being able to download the file. Do you have an idea what is wrong?

A screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I just cancelled that box and carried on downloading typesafe activator [here](https://www.playframework.com/download). Can you do the same? Then use the `activator` console to get all the resources in the normal way. Not sure why that is coming up now, prob just a glitch. Or just use [this](http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.2.10/typesafe-activator-1.2.10-minimal.zip) link. Works for me.

Comment: If I cancel that, download doesn't get started automatically and none of the download links seem to be working since clicking on those doesn't start the download. But this is the case with Firefox, thanks to @Rich, I treid Chrome and after a short delay, the download starts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Play Framework download page embeds an image from the CloudBees website. At some point the CloudBees image (`logo_small.png`) was probably accessible, but now it is forbidden. Since it is not important to see the CloudBees image, you can try cancelling the dialog box. When I view the page in Chrome I don't see the error at all unless I use the developer tools.

Comment: Chrome gets along with that problem, but Firefox doesn't. Thank you for mentioning Chrome.

Comment: This is fixed now on playframework.com: https://github.com/playframework/playframework.com/pull/2

Comment: @Metallica Strange, I browse with Firefox and it worked with me when the error was occurring. But glad it's all sorted now anyway.

Comment: I reproduced the error before fixing it using Firefox on Mac OS.

Comment: Now again I cannot download Play on OS X Yosemite with any browser! I did install it using Homebrew which is by the way my favourite package manager, but you get disappointed when you choose Play over Rails and then you encounter something like this! If a web development framework cannot manage to fix its own website problem, how is it going to create a good scalable website? Doesn't anybody really download and use Play these days? How do they download it?

Comment: I'm sorry it isn't working for you. https://www.playframework.com/download works for me in both Chrome and Firefox on OS X Mavericks. When I look in the network inspector all responses are 200. There are no authentication errors. Can you explain what's happening for you? Does it happen when you use a different computer or when you use your phone? What about when you're on a different network?